# Memory leak, when using GLM

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, glm-math

I use `glm` (Opengl Math) in my SDL+OpenGL project. But I've noticed, that the code may leak memory. Here is an example:

```
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

int foo()
{
        glm::vec4 Position = glm::vec4(glm::vec3(0.0), 1.0);
        glm::mat4 Model = glm::mat4(1.0);
        Model[4] = glm::vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glm::vec4 Transformed = Model * Position;
        return 0;
}
```

In the first line we create a new `glm::vec3` instance, but at the end of the function we don't free the allocated memory. If I call the function `foo` in a loop, then will it leak memory?

Comment: Stack allocations are always freed when they go out of scope. Only heap allocations have to be freed (which is here not the case).

Comment: You don't leak memory, but unless `glm` uses 1-based indices, accessing `Model[4]` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the instances aren't being created using `new`, they will be placed on the stack, not on the heap. Therefore, when the stack used by `foo` is cleared, the memory for these instances will be re-claimed.

Answer (score 2):

The variables you're creating have *automatic storage duration*, meaning they will be automatically cleaned up when they go out of scope.

For the temporary `glm::vec3`, it's by the end of the statement. So, no memory leak here.

Memory leaks can only occur with the use of *dynamic storage duration*, i.e. variables allocated with `new` or `malloc`.